# Issues when carrying medication on an airplane when travelling to Germany?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, germany, drugs

I am going to fly to Germany tomorrow. I wished to take few tablets and syrup for cold,fever etc. Now I want to know whether there is any problem to carry drugs. Moreover it is my first trip, so please tell me any other possible issues during German trip.

Comment: In general I would say that's not a problem, but there several if's there. Can you give more information about your place of departure? are you carrying those in your checked in or hand luggage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No issues as long as you put it in your checked luggage.

Refer to [Health Information for Traveler](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/germany) page.

> Remember to pack extras of important health supplies in case of travel delays. This is especially important for items that may be difficult to get at your destination, like prescription medicines.

Note that for special medicine/equipment like Needles or syringes, you may need a letter from your doctor.

Comment: You can also carry medications absolutely essential to an existing condition in your carry-on luggage, and those will also typically require a letter from your doctor.

Comment: I find that page to a bit vague. If you check the offical page of the German customs authority (http://www1.zoll.de/english_version/a0_passenger_traffic/e0_vub/g0_medicines/priv_imports/index.html), you'll find generally, all private import of medicines is prohibited, with the exception of "quantities as would normally be used while travelling". So you can't for example bring along medication "for a friend". Generally it is advised, if you are unsure, then use the "red exit" at customs and declare what you have with you. That way you won't be fined if you do have any illegal medication.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a lot of prescription medicine that I take, and I travel all over the world.  In general:

- it needs to still be in the pharmacy containers
- it should be sealed
- if it's liquid, you may need to declare it at security, before boarding the plane, and show evidence that it's medicinal
- always bring the prescription with you as evidence that a doctor has ordered it for you
- I usually carry a summary of my medical conditions, as described by a doctor. However I think I've only ever used it once and that wasn't in an airport / on a plane.

**There's very few *prescription* drugs that a country won't let you bring in, as long as you have the evidence for this being necessary for your condition, and evidence that it's been prescribed.**